# Is there anything wrong with this database class's execute query function?

Tags: asp.net, database, enterprise-library

So I have this old code being used, that runs simple ExecuteNonQuery command for database calls. I'm using DbConnection, DbTransaction and other System.Data.Common commands.

I seem to get a lot of Null Reference errors whenever I use the function in certain parts of the project, though it seems fine in other parts. I think it has to do with opening connections manually or some problem with calling it, but I'm wondering if the function itself is badly designed originally (shouldn't there be a way to fix any problems in the way it is called?)

I feel when transactions are involved, these null reference errors come up more often, I think the error I get is null exception at **"_command = _db.GetStoredProcCommand(storedProcedure);"** inside the following function. But that stored procedure does exist, so it makes no sense.

```
public List<OutputParameter> execute(String storedProcedure, StoredProcedureParameter[] sqlParameters)
{
  try
  {
      List<OutputParameter> outputParameters = new List<OutputParameter>();
      _command = _db.GetStoredProcCommand(storedProcedure);

    for (int x = 0; x < sqlParameters.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
      if (sqlParameters[x] != null)
      {
        StoredProcedureParameter sqlParameter = sqlParameters[x];
        String param = sqlParameter.ParameterName;

        DbType dbType = sqlParameter.DbType;
        object value = sqlParameter.Value;
        if (sqlParameter.IsOutputParam)
        {
          _db.AddOutParameter(_command, param, dbType, 32);

          OutputParameter outputParameter = new OutputParameter(param);
          outputParameters.Add(outputParameter);
        }
        else
          _db.AddInParameter(_command, param, dbType, value);
      }
    }
    if (_transaction == null)
      _db.ExecuteNonQuery(_command);
    else
      _db.ExecuteNonQuery(_command, _transaction);

    foreach (OutputParameter op in outputParameters)
    {
      op.ParameterValue = _db.GetParameterValue(_command, op.ParameterName);
    }

    return outputParameters;
  }
  catch (SqlException sqle)
  {
    throw new DataAccessException(sqle.ToString());
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    throw new DataAccessException(e.ToString());
  }
}
```

Comment: Where is `_command` defined? Where else is it accessed?

Comment: private DbCommand _command = null;   --- it isn't uh, initiated except through this GetStoredProcCommand stuff. It's accessed in other functions like QueryDatabase(), which bring back results instead of just executing like execute().

Comment: And in how many places are you accessing it? Are you using `execute` in many places in your code?

Comment: Yes, one after another over and over in many places. Just the way this legacy code was designed. I had to remove a lot of code like this: if (da.getConnectionState() == ConnectionState.Closed) da.openConnection();    ----- because it was causing some sorts of crashes and stopping the execution of the whole website due to null references.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `_command` variable appears to be a field and as such a shared member.

As such your code is *very* susceptible to multithreading issues (if two functions call this class with different stored procedures, what happens?).

A `Command` should also be closed and disposed of properly, which is not happening in your code, not explicitly anyways.

Comment: I thought asp.net and the fact that websites are usually pretty linear, makes it so that nothing is multithreaded, like PHP has no multithreading unless you use POSIX functions. Lemme guess, I'm wrong? So how should I code it to fix this? Should command not be a private variable, and more a local variable using 'using' ?

Comment: @Dexter - It is very easy to add threads to asp.net, so assuming that your code will only ever run on a single fully isolated thread may bring trouble. You hit the nail on the head - local variable, with a `using` statement.

Comment: Didn't solve the issue though. Maybe something else is null, like _conn or _command. Which are initialized in the dataaccess class construction creation: 
    public DataAccess()
    {
      _db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
      _conn = _db.CreateConnection();
    }

Comment: @Dexter - possibly. Without seeing the complete code for the class and the functions it calls it is impossible to say for certain. You should debug using `break on exception` and follow the stack trace.

Comment: It's pretty much been impossible to do so. Debug does not work, breakpoints don't work on this project. I been using logging and looking at the exception stacktrace. Just now I found some more of that da.OpenConnection() stuff, and commented them out, and suddenly everything is working now. Still do not understand why, it's like voodoo :S.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting a null reference exception in the line `_command = _db.GetStoredProcCommand(storedProcedure);` then the only thing that can be null there is `_db`. The storedProcedure is just a parameter and _command could happily be null without a problem.

Since you aren't actually doing anything in the code to make sure that _db exists and is valid, open, etc. then this is most likely the problem.

Comment: Here's the problem, when I had if (da.getConnectionState() == ConnectionState.Closed) da.openConnection();   in some areas of the code, it was also causing errors. So I removed any open connections because someone told me that opening connections manually is WRONG because it is automatically managed. And it solved many problems (there's still some of that code left somewhere in here). _db is initialized when the class is initialized. 
      _db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();